# How to Delete Animation Panels?

Tags: interface

Okay so I have a slight problem. [image: the problem]

I can't figure out how to get rid of the animation panels? Please help, I'm quite new to blender so sorry if this is quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! Yes, the panels... the most annoying noob thing in Blender!

Here is it:
[image]

Comment: These are not panels. These are editor windows.

Comment: agreed but from the screenshot provided  in the question I assume that's what @Tabs wants to deal with. If not I will be pleased to delete my answer and he should rephrase his question!

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bugging me for ages and I couldn't find any info on the sites I was looking at. You've saved me :D